# Converting seconds into minutes within a query

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a data grid on my form that is populated using the following:

```
SELECT [Activity_Date], [Activity_duration_seconds] * FROM tblActivity
```

Is there any way that I can add an extra field onto this query that returns minutes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute whatever you want:

```
SELECT Column1, 
       Activity_duration_seconds, 
       Activity_duration_seconds / 60 AS Activity_duration_minutes 
FROM tblActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by 60 to get minutes:

```
select Activity_duration_seconds / 60 as activity_duration_minutes 
    from tblActivity
```

(Assuming activity_duration_seconds is an integer column, 60 is also an integer, so you'll get it rounded down to whole minutes).

Or if you want minutes including the fractional part, then 60.0 will tell the db to treat it as a decimal:

```
select Activity_duration_seconds / 60.0 as activity_duration_minutes 
    from tblActivity
```

And you'd get 2.05 or something like that, so part minutes too.